# PHP timeout when connecting to mssql under apache

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, pdo

PHP Version 5.4,
Apache Version 2.4,
CentOS 7.3

Trying to connect to mssql db using the following php code which works fine when I run it from the command line. However, when I place code under apache (on same server) and call through browser I get a timeout error.

> Error: Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HYT00] SQLConnect: 0
>   [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout
>   expired+

```
set_time_limit(30);
echo "+ Connection\n";
try {
    $pdo = new PDO("odbc:sqlsrv_msodbc", "username", "password");
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: Please use set_time_limit(0);

Comment: Hi - tried that but got same error result.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue. I am using CentOS 7.3 in vagrant and solved it by disabling SELinux.

If you're on a dev environment and disabling SELinux is cool you can do it by:

```
sudo vi /etc/sysconfig/selinux
```

Set

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

I found this over at serverfault: https://serverfault.com/questions/240015/how-do-i-allow-mysql-connections-through-selinux

Comment: Thanks Sean256! That worked. Wow - never thought of it.

Comment: No problem! Mind giving a brother a correct answer mark?

Comment: Trying! Don't have the reputations yet!