# Error while connecting to MS SQL via PDO-ODBC on CentOS (PHP)

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, centos, odbc

I am doing this:

```
$dbh = new PDO ('odbc:DRIVER=MSODBC17;SERVERNAME=mssql;DATABASE='."$dbname", "$username", "$pw");
```

I am using this driver:

```
 27 [MSODBC17]
 28 Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
 29 Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.0.so.1.1
 30 UsageCount=1
```

And I get this error message:

> SQLSTATE[08001] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Neither DSN nor SERVER keyword supplied

Any suggestion what is causing this/how it could be fixed?

---

When I try this:

```
$dbh = new PDO ("odbc:DRIVER=MSODBC17;SERVER=$hostname;PORT=$port;DATABASE=$dbname", "$username", "$pw");
```

I get a slightly different error:

> SQLSTATE[HYT00] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired

Comment: never tried on linux but are you sure about your `SERVERNAME=mssql` seams weird as a server name

Comment: @MacBooc No, it's what I've found in an example online... The driver is good though.

Comment: could you try with `DRIVER=MSODBC17;Server=yourIPOrLocalhost;` ?

Comment: @MacBooc, tried. Same error.

Comment: @MacBooc I've made an update and got a different error, please take a look...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42087820/php-timeout-when-connecting-to-mssql-under-apache maybe it coulb be solve by this now. Edit: or more this by the way https://serverfault.com/questions/240015/how-do-i-allow-mysql-connections-through-selinux

Comment: @MacBooc Disabled SELinux but didn't work also...

Comment: are you able to connect on it with CMD ? also, it seams that the port should be write as `$hostname,$port`

Comment: @MacBooc Woah! `$hostname,$port` worked! Thanks!

Comment: nice you're welcome :)